FileStream with a blank line
I must write an xml file and convert in base64.
I create the file but if i convert the results in base64 and i decode from base64 to text i have a blank line before the last. why ?
This is the code :
   Dim utf8WithoutBom As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding(False)
   Dim fs As New FileStream(_percorso, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
   Dim XML_wr As New XmlTextWriter(fs, utf8WithoutBom) With {.Formatting = Formatting.Indented}
   Dim crlf = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(vbCrLf)
   XML_wr.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
   XML_wr.Indentation = 7
   XML_wr.WriteStartDocument()
   XML_wr.WriteStartElement("DespatchAdvice")
   XML_wr.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:DespatchAdvice-2")
   XML_wr.Flush()
   fs.Write(crlf, 0, 1)
   XML_wr.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:cac", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2")
   XML_wr.Flush()
   fs.Write(crlf, 0, 1)
   XML_wr.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:cbc", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2")
   XML_wr.Flush()
   XML_wr.WriteStartElement("cbc:CustomizationID")
XML_wr.WriteString("urn:fdc:peppol.eu:poacc:trns:despatch_advice:3:extended:urn:www.agid.gov.it:trns:ddt:3.1")
   XML_wr.WriteEndElement()  
   XML_wr.Flush()

In some examples I find .write with just a parameter but i'm using framework 4.8 and my write has 3 parameters.

Do you know what the 3rd parameter is for? Writing a buffer, you usually specify its length. Why don't you simply write that carriage return + line feed as a string? You also have a UTF-8 encoder, but you're getting the bytes of that string with Unicode encoding (UTF-16LE, two bytes per char in this plane)

Yes, 3rd parameter is length. I white in that way because they suggested it to me here on the forum and it seemed to work. What would you say you do? If i use Scrivi.WriteString(vbCrLf) after the first attribute this close the attribute with > and after i have an error for incorrect xml

If you want to keep this form (of writing to the file), first thing try Dim crlf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(vbCrLf) fs.Write(crlf, 0, crlf.Length)

Have you tried using an XmlWriter instead of an XmlTextWriter, as I suggested in a previous answer?
